# How can I get the application datasource name in Coldfusion 10?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

In Coldfusion 9 to get the application datasource outside application.cfc, I've used `application.getApplicationSettings().datasource`.

In Coldfusion 10 `getApplicationSettings()` has been replaced with `ApplicationGetMetadata()`.
So naturally I tried `ApplicationGetMetaData().datasource`, but the `ApplicationGetMetaData()` function doesn't currently work... (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSf23b27ebc7b554b6c43bda313671e094bb-8000.html) and comments).

So how can I get the application datasource name (this.datasource in application.cfc) from outside the application.cfc in CF10?

Comment: ColdFusion 10 Backport: GetApplicationMetadata - http://misterdai.yougeezer.co.uk/2012/03/16/coldfusion-10-backport-arrayslice-getapplicationmetadata/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no ColdFusion function called `ApplicationGetMetaData`. The correct function name is `GetApplicationMetaData()`.

You can get the application's `datasource` by calling `GetApplicationMetaData().datasource`.

Comment: apparently the function was renamed between CF10 prerelease and the final release (https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3208541)
The old documentation for applicationGetMetadata was still online until exactly today :)

Comment: Indeed: http://bit.ly/USX0UZ (the cached version of the docs page for `ApplicationGetMetaData()`)

Comment: @Adam: Please don't use URL shorteners here. They're not necessary. Worse, they're often blocked by enterprise firewalls because they can be a vector for malware.

Comment: I can't help but think there might be better things to do with your time, Al, but here's the original unabridged URL:

Comment: Sigh... I overran my 5min edit timeout.  S/O can be really nazi at times.  *HERE* is the original unabridged URL:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KHSJN8PAYX4J:help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSf23b27ebc7b554b6c43bda313671e094bb-8000.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

I'm pleased you think I might be the sort of person to spread malware.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @Adam - I think you misread Al's comment. He is not saying *you* are spreading malware, just that some corporate firewalls are extremely restrictive. Ridiculously so at times. If they see a shortened url they automatically block it - no exceptions. (It does not matter that it might point to a perfectly legitimate site.) So anyone reading S.O. from behind such a firewall wouldn't be able to access the site you referenced.